# Sources of good, free icons/images for applications & web apps with permissive license?

Tags: image, resources, icons, media, favicon

I'm interested in finding good icons/images that can be used in both 'free' and proprietary programs.

Please include a description of any license restrictions associated with the source of the icons you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

I use two search engines:

[IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.net/index.php?q=file) and [IconLook](http://www.iconlook.com/search.icon?q=file&s12=on&s16=on&s22=on&s32=on&s48=on&s64=on&s128=on).

If you can't find what you want, this [blog post](http://speckyboy.com/2008/03/04/top-40-free-icon-resources-for-web-designers-updated-speckyboy/) has a list of great resources.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Silk Icons (http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) on a few projects. It's covered under the creative commons license so you will have to include a link back to the site somewhere in your app.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.iconarchive.com has a nice selection

Answer (score 1):

I used [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) to find icons.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the best luck with [Icon Buffet](http://www.iconbuffet.com) and [StockIcons](http://stockicons.com)

Answer (score 0):

A [good starting point](http://www.iconsreview.com/), and a [nice stock icon site](http://www.icons-icons.com/).  Some require payment, but there are lots of free sources out there.  However, one of your highest priorities for a commercial application is that it looks good enough to buy - [$30 for a good set is cheap](http://kalzumeus.com/2006/08/25/outsourcing-for-the-uisv/) compared to the time it takes you to research and find a set, nevermind the time it'd take for you to make them yourself.

-Adam